# How to use the npm 'mysql-import' module in node.js - TypeScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, import

I am trying to import a dump to a database, i am working with node.js and the `'mysql-import'` npm module.
I first wrote the code in JavaScript, then tried to alter it for TypeScript. In JS the code works perfectly. In TS I get the following errors:

1. `"This expression is not constructable. Type 'typeof import("url") has no construct signatures."`
   I've tried `{ Importer }`, that returns a different error, `"Importer only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."`
2. `Parameter 'progress' implicitly has an 'any' type.` This makes sense, since the `imp.onProgress((progress)=>{` parameter doesn't have a type. I am not sure which type to give it, though.

I am quite new to type script, and after spending far too much time on this, I am forced to acknowledge that my googling skills have failed me. Any help to get this to work in type script will be much appropriated.

NB! the npm package seems to be installed correctly.

```
import Importer from 'mysql-import';


// Import file to database
export async function ImportData(dbNew: string[]){
    await Promise.resolve(CleanDatabase(dbNew)).then(function(){
        const imp = new Importer({
            host:dbNew[0], 
            user:dbNew[1],
            password:dbNew[2], 
            database:dbNew[3]
        });
        
        try {
            imp.onProgress((progress)=>{
                var percent = Math.floor(progress.bytes_processed / progress.total_bytes * 10000) / 100;
                console.log(`${percent}% Completed`);
            });
    
            imp.import('./zelanard_c_sheet.sql').then(()=>{
                var files_imported = imp.getImported();
                console.log(`${files_imported.length} SQL file(s) imported.`);
            }).catch((err: string[]) =>{
                console.error(err);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem...

```
const Importer = require('mysql-import');
```

Comment: I've removed the "I don't really understand why though. Can someone explain it?" from your answer. If you want to ask a question, either edit your question to put the question there, or post a new question. Don't post questions in answers though.